# finding wifi when using systemd

Tags: wpa-supplicant, systemd-networkd

Many guides explain how to setup wifi connections when you know the SSID and the WPA2 Key. But what to do when you doesn't know the SSID, or you wanna use a public AP, or just need a list of available APs/routers.

In other words: I am looking for an equivalent of `iw list` with **systemd**.

I get the feeling using  a notebook for traveling with systemd-networkd installed isn't that easy then using networkmanager.

Comment: Have you looked into `iwd` and its CLI client `iwctl`? I use this rather than the NetworkManager beaste. `iwctl` has an excellent `help` command.

Comment: nope, wasn't aware of `iwctl` nor `iwd`. both aren't installed by default. I will have a look at both. thx

Comment: You will have to start/enable iwd once installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `iw scan`.

```
$ sudo iw dev <ifname> scan | egrep '^BSS |SSID:|signal:|Authentication suites:'
```

This gives you a list of APs, including their SSID and authentication suites. As you pointed out, there are many guides on how to connect to WiFi, and now you (probably) have all the information you need.

If nothing is listed under authentication suites, then no psk is required to connect. Although I'd avoid using open, public WiFi altogether unless you're using a VPN. Or unless the AP is a trusted AP, is WPA3, and supports WiFi Enhanced Open, which is very unlikely.